Is there any way to add the modern script editor web part to the title area of a SharePoint Online page?
Is there any way to add the modern script editor web part to the title area of a SharePoint Online page? The customization options in the edit do not allow adding javascript.

You can add the modern script editor in any web part on the page. With JavaScript, you can manipulate the DOM everywhere, included for the title area.
Reference: Script editor web part for modern pages

In modern SharePoint Online, the classic Script Editor web part is not available due to security and performance considerations. However, you can achieve similar customizations using alternatives like SharePoint Framework (SPFx) extensions or embedding scripts using the Embed web part or the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web parts designed for specific functionalities. These approaches maintain security while offering flexibility for customizations.
